# to_csv doesn't save all the rows?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
data = pd.read_csv("location")
data = reduce_data(data, 0.10)
data = data.reset_index()

data['NewColumn'] = data.apply(somefunction_works, axis=1)
os.makedirs("location", exist_ok=True)

print(data) -> prints all the data properly
data.to_csv("location/file.tsv", sep="\t") -> in the file there is only the first row
```

I really don't know the reason for that it may be because that new column created is really long is there a limit of bytes to save with to csv. Please help.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? What version of pandas are you using? Can you describe the dataset or give a link to it? Can you show what `somefunction_works` and `reduce_data` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the data.to_csv("location/file.tsv", sep="\t") to data.to_csv("location/file.csv", sep="\t") and it worked after that when I changed it back to data.to_csv("location/file.tsv", sep="\t") and gave a restart it worked so I dont know what was the problem but fixed